# Canonical way to call 'Run Command' on a VM from Datafactory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-vm

I need to execute various batch scripts located in a VM within my Resource Group. The call of these scripts needs to be orchestrated by Datafactory.

I learned about `Run Command` in VM, and which can be used via PowerShell or Rest API. I was wondering if any of these ways is recommended to include in a Datafactory pipeline.

My approach at this point would be to use a `Web Activity` to do the API calls, one for each script.

My question: Is there a more recommended way to do this? Do you see any bottleneck or situation that may be a problem with this approach?

Comment: How did you completed this process? can you elaborate? how did you made the CMD call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the easiest way to achieve this, one point you need to pay attention to is the [`Authentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#authentication) when using the `Web activity`, remember to choose the `Managed Identity`, and specify the `Resource` with `https://management.azure.com/`.

[image]

To call the REST API - [`Virtual Machines Run Commands - Run Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual%20machines%20run%20commands/runcommand) successfully in `Web activity`, you also need to give the RBAC role to the Managed Identity(MSI).

Navigate to the subscription or the VM in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for the name of your ADFv2 and add it as an `Owner/Contributor` role.

[image]

If you are not familiar with  Managed Identity(MSI), refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). Also make sure your ADFv2 has the MSI, when creating data factory through `Azure portal` or `PowerShell`, managed identity will always be created automatically, if not, follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity#generate-managed-identity) to generate managed identity.